# Flutter: Firebase: Crashlytics: How to decode crashes caused by Cloud_Firestore? 100% of my crashes are caused by 'CloudFirestorePlugin.java'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Over the past two months, my app has become significantly more complex. I use Transactions to complete 90% of all document writes client side. I have added quite a few listeners recently as well. Over the apps development, a linear increase in transaction and listener usage has caused an exponential spike in crashes. These crashes are just from testing using one device! Furthermore, the crashes happen exclusively on Android devices...

These are the four causes of every crash my app has seen:

1. io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:613)
2. io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$DocumentObserver.onEvent (CloudFirestorePlugin.java:429)
3. io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$EventObserver.onEvent (CloudFirestorePlugin.java:451)
4. io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground (CloudFirestorePlugin.java:633)

The information provided doesn't help in narrowing down the problem. I would normally assume that I am doing something wrong, but the fact that this occurs exclusively on android devices leads me to believe something is wrong at the package level. Digging online through forums and documentation it appears I am not alone with this Firestore Transaction/Listener related issue.

Has anybody had similar issues and found a solution? This isn't only a problem for me, it's a show stopper.

Is it possible that since introducing listeners I have created this problem?

Comment: If you have a bug report for Cloud Firestore SDKs for Android, create an issue on its GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-firestore. For Flutter, use https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: As mentioned by @DougStevenson Github is the best way to go, also I found [this issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2526) which looks pretty similiar to yours, it happens only on Android with Flutter and it heppens on the listeners

Comment: Thanks for the digging both. @Edgardo That finding might be worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [known issue on github](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2526), please confirm but the issue only occurs on Android -Fluter with the listeners.

They mentioned:

> Just waiting for the green signal to make sure this doesn't catch some other edge cases and I can go ahead with a fix patch.

You shoudl post that your are being affected also and followup there.